# How to determine what action a SQL trigger fires on

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Is there a SQL statement that can be used to determine in what events a table trigger will fire?

E.g. Given this trigger:

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[tr_Stuff_upd_del] ON [dbo].[TABLE]
FOR UPDATE, DELETE
AS
...
```

is there a statement that will tell me that it will run for updates and deletes. I could check the trigger definition for the specific text, but surely there is a more elegant way?

---

**Edit**: The main issue I'm having is I'm not sure what the correct term is.So here is attempt number 2: I can use the below script to get triggers that contain the text `DELETE` anywhere in it.. Now how do I include in that list if the trigger will fire `FOR DELETE`, `AFTER UPDATE`, `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` etc..

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.[name] AS trigger_name,t.name as table_name
FROM sys.sql_modules AS m 
    INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON m.object_id = o.object_id 
    INNER JOIN sys.objects t on t.object_id = o.parent_object_id
    WHERE o.type='TR'
        and m.definition LIKE '%DELETE%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find this in [`sys.trigger_events`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187322.aspx)

```
SELECT type_desc
FROM   sys.trigger_events
WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[tr_Stuff_upd_del]')
```

--

```
+-----------+
| type_desc |
+-----------+
| UPDATE    |
| DELETE    |
+-----------+
```

Comment: Ah! Now that's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can determine action that fired the trigger by examining presence of data in `inserted` and `deleted` tables available in trigger.

1. There is data only in `inserted` - it was `insert`.
2. There are data both in `deleted` and `inserted` - it was `update`.
   In this case `inserted` table contains values after update and `deleted` table contains values before update.
3. There is data only in `deleted` - it was `delete`.

Comment: The question asks what it *will* fire on. Not what it *did* fire on

Comment: Thanks, and this is excellent... when inside the trigger. But I'm looking to list the triggers. I've updated my question accordingly

Comment: @Balah ooh.... it looks I've completely misunderstood your initially phrased question.....

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Maybe you misunderstood OP, but this is the answer *I* was looking for :) Thanks